# What is "moral goodness" according to Kant?

Tags: ethics, kant

"Immanuel Kant argues that mere conformity with the moral law is not sufficient for moral goodness." In this context what is the literal meaning of "moral goodness" in simple terms?

Comment: Can you provide the original reference source?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember Kant wrote the "highest good" is honesty in:

KANT, I.  1781.  The canon of pure reason: section II: of the ideal of the highest good, as a determining ground of the ultimate end of pure reason.  (In Weigelt, M. ed. Immanuel Kant: critique of pure reason.  London: Penguin Classics, 2007)

Comment: If speaking of the highest good (which goes into the right direction), one can refer to the *Critique of Practical Reason* for the theoretical arguments (outright contradicting the first critique sometimes), and to the *Metaphysics of Morals* and *Religion*, maybe *Anthropology*, for the more practical aspects and especially how this is linked to his notion of *character*. Apart from that: Could you elaborate on the link between moral goodness and honesty? Sounds interesting!

Comment: The link is related to creativity and "the Creator". Honesties cause correspondence causes creativity and change.